# Branch instruction with direct jump in LLVM

Tags: c++, c, llvm

In LLVM, how can I have generate a branch instruction that jumps directly, rather than having if-else. I know there is LLVM::BranchInst class, but don't know how to use it for this purpose, or do I need to use some other class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need an unconditional branch:

```
static BranchInst * llvm::BranchInst::Create(BasicBlock *IfTrue,
                                             Instruction *InsertBefore = 0)

static BranchInst * llvm::BranchInst::Create(BasicBlock *IfTrue,
                                             BasicBlock *InsertAtEnd)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [this method](http://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1BranchInst.html#a77b75549a5089f42fa422070a3676c48):

```
static BranchInst *     Create (BasicBlock *IfTrue, BasicBlock *InsertAtEnd)
```

The first argument is where you are jumping to and the second one is where created instruction should be placed.